# Why method passed as argument wont work here

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this code in my Node/Express API. It works

```
router.get('/auth',function(req, res, next){

  var callback = function(redirectUrl){
    return res.redirect(redirectUrl);
  }

  auth.beginOauth(callback);

});
```

But if I modify this code to something like this. It will not work -

```
router.get('/auth',function(req, res, next){

  auth.beginOauth(res.redirect);

});
```

Why when method is passed directly, it wont work?

Comment: *won't work* if pretty vague.  What error or issue are you seeing?

Comment: It could be to do with the fact that when you pass it in as `callback`, `beginOauth` is returned a value.  But when you pass in `res.redirect` it isn't.

Comment: @DavinTryon I am not looking for error resolution. JS support method passing as argument. Which should work

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what "won't work" means :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could be that the execution context is different.

When you say `res.redirect(redirectUrl)`, `this` inside the `redirect` method is referring to the `res` object(unless a custom execution context is used), but when you pass `res.redirect` as a callback, when the callback is invoked the context is lost.

```
router.get('/auth',function(req, res, next){   
    auth.beginOauth(res.redirect.bind(res));
});
```

Comment: It works. You were right as the context was not correct.